# JQuery UI Context Menu Options

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am successfully using the JQuery UI Context Menu in my project. However, the menus are a bit slow for my taste. This reason is the hide and show effects. I would like to override these options. Is there any way to do this? Without changing the JavaScript source code?

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `show` option?

Comment: Wow. That worked. Thank you.